# select procedure which should find word by provided letters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have procedure it is working  but i want to improve it, by giving ability  to search by couple letters in word. Procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE SearchByIncIDroNameOfClientoStreetorEmpID
@IncID int,
@NameOfClient nvarchar (60),
@StrID int,
@EmpID int,
@date date
as
select IncID,NameOfClient,EnterDate,StrName ,AppartmentNumber as 'appartment',Summary,IncStatus,e.LastName,EndDate 
from Incident i 
JOIN Streets s on i.StrID=s.StrID 
join Employee e on i.EmpID=e.EmpID
where  IncID =@IncID or NameOfClient = @NameOfClient or s.StrID = @StrID or i.EmpID=@EmpID or EnterDate =@date
go
```

I need modify this part `NameOfClient = @NameOfClient` so it will show records which begins with  provided letter. so right  now if i want to searh for `John` i have to wright John but I want for example if i will give just `Jo` it should return me all of the records which starts from `Jo` 
I was trying to add % sign before `@NameOfClient` but it doesn't work. Any Ideas how I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `like` operator:

```
NameOfClient like @NameOfClient+'%'
```

Comment: Do you know how to do same for int and date fields?

Comment: i tried use like for `IncID  like @IncID` but it doesn't work :)

Comment: i am trying to give them ability  to search by first number in accident for example show all incident which starts from 5 buy providing only 5  and it for example will show 500, 501, 503,...

Comment: For dates and ints you can convert them to varchar first, eg: `convert(varchar(10), Date, 120)` `convert(varchar, intValue)` and use it just as with `NameOfClient` but this can impact the performance.

Comment: couldn't figured it out how to convert?

Comment: I did `EnterDate =convert(varchar(10), @date, 120)+ '%'` but it throws error `Error converting data type varchar to date.`

Comment: `convert(varchar, IncID) like @IncID+'%' 
or NameOfClient like @NameOfClient+'%' 
or convert(varchar(10), EnterDate, 120) like @date+'%'`
For this to work you need to change SP parameter types to varchar as `like` operator works only for text types

Comment: @AndreyIvanov You should stick to answers you chose :) doing the same with int was altogether a different question

Answer (score 2):

```
NameOfClient like @NameOfClient + '%'
```

Doesn't this works?

Comment: is it possible do same for int fields?

Comment: Why would you need so. Integer columns are not for partial matches. You can try though I think It will work.

Comment: I want to customer be able to search by part of InncedentID

Answer (score 0):

You must use the LIKE operator:

```
WHERE NameOfClient LIKE @NameOfClient
```